# Exchange 2010 Out of office doesn't show original senders email address

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, email

When one of our users is on holiday they will set their Out of office message and change the Out of office rule to forward all emails received to a colleague. This has always worked very well for us while we were using Exchange 2003, but now we have some of our Mailboxes on Exchange 2010 the behaviour seems to have changed (for the worse).

### Exchange 2003

Mailboxes located on Exchange 2003 will send the following message to the person defined in the Out of office forwarding rule. Notice that the original senders email address (in this case my personal email address) is shown.

[image]

### Exchange 2010

When the Out of office forwarding rule kicks in for Mailboxes on Exchange 2010 the email is forwarded on as normal, but notice that the original senders email address *is not* shown on the forwarded message.

[image]

This causes us a problem, because the whole idea of having emails forwarded on to somebody else is so they can deal with the enquiries and orders that come in while the other person is on holiday. If the person dealing with the forwarded emails needs to contact the customer, Exchange 2003 made this easy by showing their email address - Exchange 2010 seems to make this impossible.

Is there an option we can change to make the original senders email address show, have Microsoft removed this feature or is there at least some workaround we can implement that will allow us to have what we need?

---

## Update 1

I have tested this with various combinations of Outlook and Exchange and here are the results of the test. As you can see, something has definitely changed in the way Exchange 2010 behaves with forwarded Out of office messages. Does show/Does not show is relating to the original senders email address.

```
+--------------+---------------+---------------+ 
|              | Exchange 2003 | Exchange 2010 |
+--------------+---------------+---------------+
| Outlook 2003 |   Does Show   | Does not show |
| Outlook 2007 |   Does Show   | Does not show |
| Outlook 2010 |   Does Show   | Does not show |
+--------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Here is the (mildly sanitised) output of `Get-RemoteDomain | fl`. I'm not entirely convinced this has anything to do with it though, as these settings are all for *outgoing* mail to domains other than our own.

```
RunspaceId                        : 1002c62b-9f50-47a0-8862-1d635c4dbdba
DomainName                        : *
IsInternal                        : False
TargetDeliveryDomain              : False
CharacterSet                      : iso-8859-1
NonMimeCharacterSet               : iso-8859-1
AllowedOOFType                    : ExternalLegacy
AutoReplyEnabled                  : True
AutoForwardEnabled                : True
DeliveryReportEnabled             : True
NDREnabled                        : True
MeetingForwardNotificationEnabled : False
ContentType                       : MimeHtmlText
DisplaySenderName                 : True
TNEFEnabled                       :
LineWrapSize                      : unlimited
TrustedMailOutboundEnabled        : False
TrustedMailInboundEnabled         : False
UseSimpleDisplayName              : False
NDRDiagnosticInfoEnabled          : True
AdminDisplayName                  :
ExchangeVersion                   : 0.0 (6.5.6500.0)
Name                              : Default
DistinguishedName                 : CN=Default,CN=Internet Message Formats,CN=Global Settings,CN=WIDGETS,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=corp,DC=acme-widgets,DC=com
Identity                          : Default
Guid                              : 0f601b72-7249-47cb-8f51-321c5d070d7f
ObjectCategory                    : corp.acme-widgets.com/Configuration/Schema/ms-Exch-Domain-Content-Config
ObjectClass                       : {top, msExchDomainContentConfig}
WhenChanged                       : 25/01/2011 17:20:34
WhenCreated                       : 10/10/2007 12:17:57
WhenChangedUTC                    : 25/01/2011 17:20:34
WhenCreatedUTC                    : 10/10/2007 11:17:57
OrganizationId                    :
OriginatingServer                 : dc2.corp.acme-widgets.com
IsValid                           : True
```

## Update 2

The suggestion by Holocryptic to use the option **Keep message intact** seems to have done the trick. It's a pain to have to do this to each computer, but so far the best "solution" I've had. Ideally I'm still looking for something server side like Exchange 2003 was, but Holocryptic is most likely to end up with this bounty.

Comment: Do you notice this behavior with other forwarded mail?  Or just with OOF?

Comment: I just left the office as I posted this, but I will check it out on Monday. Could you define "other forwarded mail" please @Holocryptic

Comment: @Ben, when forwarding other mail items, you'll see smtp or mailto links in the first forwarded message and not subsequent messages in the chain (if there's been multiple emails back and forth). Here's a screenshot of what I mean. https://picasaweb.google.com/108798697118943580107/WebUploads?authkey=Gv1sRgCN3J6If4lqOuxgE&feat=directlink. Does your forwarded mail act like that, or does it show the same symptoms of your OOF? I'm afraid my current answer probably won't do you any good, but I'll edit it when we get closer to a solution.

Comment: Oh right, just regular forward (sorry I thought you meant some other type of auto-forwarding)! No, we just have names, no addresses show on a normal forward.

Comment: Also, what version of Outlook are your users using?  It may have bearing on the problem.

Comment: We're a mixture of Outlook 2003, 2007 and 2010.

Comment: And the Exchange 03 users are using 03 and 07 Outlook, and the Exchange 2010 users are using 07 and 2010?  Or all client versions are on each server?

Comment: And do you have the following options set on you Hub Transport?  http://thisishelpful.com/allow-exchange-2003-2007-2010-send-office-messages.html

Comment: This is one of my pet hates about exchange. There's all sorts of ways in which it's possible to 'lose' the originating email address and many more where it's pretty well hidden. It does the same with 'To' fields. I have a couple of list subscription addresses with their own names. I'd so much prefer to have the X-Envelope-To: header shown, rather than exchange pulling the Full Name attribute from AD for all of them.

Comment: @Ben Pilbrow, looks like someone is having the same/similar problem you're having.  http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Server_Software/Email_Servers/Exchange/Q_26795376.html  At this point my google-fu is not turning up much.  I'll keep looking...

Comment: Hrm this is crazy that nobody (from my Googling as well) has never experienced this problem (in words that I can describe at least). I fear we'll eventually have to bite the bullet and call Microsoft on this one.

Comment: @Ben I think this is the expected behavior for e-mail addresses that are internal to the Exchange server.  If you e-mail from an external address do you get the full e-mail address in the forward?

Comment: @Scott Warren - no, that's my whole point :-) I couldn't care less if it did it with internal people - there's a GAL and you shall use it! External people are what's causing us the problem, for reasons described in my question.

Comment: @Ben, have you tried SmallClanger's suggestion in the comments to my answer?  Does it change anything?

Comment: @Ben, well sweet.  However, I posted my answer before you posted the bounty, so peanuts to me :)  I'm glad something worked, though.

Comment: @Holocryptic - I'm pretty sure I can award you the bounty (the button is there at least). There will be a ranting meta post otherwise :-) I'm going to award it tomorrow - I'm just trying to squeeze the last few hours of exposure on the *Featured* page :-)

Answer (score 2):

How do you have your forwarding rule set up?  Have you tried setting the forward method to "keep message intact"?  Via [this link](http://www2.wlv.ac.uk/its/selfhelp/help/manage_account/forwarding_email_staff_outlook.asp).

It's possible Rollup 2 [fixes the issue](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983549), but you'll want to go to rollup 5 (as apparently that allows you to uninstall Exchange after installing any previous rollup.  Weird.)

Comment: There's another option in that rule setup: `Insert Message As Attachment`. That sounds similar to what I ask users to do when sending me problem messages, as it's the only way to preserve all the headers. Maybe that would work better for OOF; since it would both be clear that it's an OOF forwarded message, but you can open the attachment and reply directly to the original sender?

Comment: @SmallClanger, it might be.  In the comments in the question, I posted a link to someone who was having similar problems.  Might not just be Ben...