# Exchange 2010 forwarding rule stripping address

Tags: exchange-2010

### Original Question

We just migrated from Exchange 2003 to Exchange 2010. We have a single mailbox that accepts emails from customers and then forwards them using server-side rules. When a message is forwarded, the sender's email address is being stripped. This does NOT happen when we manually forward the message from within an Outlook client.

Examples of the From: line are shown below for clarity.

Auto-forward rule:

```
From: Joe Person
```

Manually forwarding within Outlook:

```
From: Joe Person [mailto:joeperson@mail.tld]
```

Does anyone know what changed in 2010 (2007?), and how to circumvent this so that we can see the email address of the original sender?

### UPDATE

As Holocryptic pointed out in the comments, this is a similar issue to the one noted in this question: [Exchange 2010 Out of office doesn't show original senders email address](https://serverfault.com/questions/240354/exchange-2010-out-of-office-doesnt-show-original-senders-email-address/240377#240377) -- Ben's situation was slightly different however, since it was dealing specifically with Out of Office replies/forwards. The options for message handling are missing in mailbox rules.

Some things I've tried, however, have come up with some interesting results:

- This behavior happens even when an entire account is set to autoforward at the mailbox level from AD or Exchange Management Console
- The only current workaround seems to be forwarding as an attachment.
- A Journal account in Exchange 2010 will receive all messages as attachments now, instead of in a forwarded manner like before. Perhaps this indicates that the behavior is working as intended?

Since forwarding the message as an attachment is exactly what we wanted to avoid, it seems I will have to leave this question open for now. If anyone else has found a better workaround, I'm ALL ears.

Comment: Tried to change a rules to redirect instead of forward, but still have the same behavior. It's been "decided" that forwarding the message as an attachment would be too disruptive to the users' workflow.

Comment: See [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/240354/exchange-2010-out-of-office-doesnt-show-original-senders-email-address/240377#240377) and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Not really :-/ BenPilbrow was using Out-Of-Office alerts.

Comment: I'm pretty sure MSFT borked something along the way dealing with how headers are handled in forwards...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you said that you changed the rules to be redirect instead of forward and it didn't resolve the issue; however, redirect is the correct action if you want to preserve the original sender.

What you might want to try is making the redirect change and implementing as transport rules on your hub or edge transports. In fact if you implement on either the hub or edge and it doesn't help you might want to try implementing on the other. Sometimes you will see different behavior depending on whether the transport rule is implemented on the hub or edge transport.

Comment: I have since left the organization. Your answer is probably closest to the correct workaround for an obvious design flaw in Exchange, so I'll give you the accept. Due to some organizational hysterical raisins, I ended up just having the forwarding set to forward as an attachment, which was clunky and sucked all forms of butt.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install **Update Rollup 2 for Exchange Server 2010.**

See [this Microsoft Knowledge basis article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983549)

Comment: Except your link is broken

Comment: Also, after looking up that rollup, I don't see anything saying that it fixes this issue.

Comment: I've fixed his link. KB983549 indeed states that update rollup 2 fixes the problem.

Comment: Installed Update Rollup 3-v3 (supersedes 2 now), rebooted all mail servers... still not fixed. KB983549 refers to a user including himself as a recipient on an email that is caught in a redirect rule.